# What does (unsigned long)1 and *(unsigned long *) mean?

Tags: c, casting, floating-point, type-conversion, bitwise-operators

This is a program that prints floating point integers bit representation. What does `*(unsigned long *)a` and `(unsigned long)1` mean?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printBits(void *a){

    int i;
    unsigned long x;
    x = *(unsigned long *)a;
    for (i = 63; i >= 0; i--){
        if ((x & ((unsigned long)1 << i)) != 0)
            printf("1");
        else
            printf("0");
        if (i == 63)
            printf(" ");
        if (i == 62)
            printf(" ");
        if (i == 52)
            printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void){
    
    double x = -145.4;
    printBits(&x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: They are typecasts.  Are you familiar with how type casting works in general?

Comment: A note on the typecast from (void*) to (unsigned long*): it should not be done this way; it should be done with memcpy to avoid strict aliasing problems. Note that if compiled with LTO in GCC the compiler is not obligated to write a double into memory to create a void pointer to it. It can inline the function call. And it can use strict alias rules to assume a double and unsigned long have nothing to do with eachother. In other words, the memory at void *a could be blank.

Comment: @NateEldredge i have seen a few examples but newer dived deep into them. Probably gonna read some articles on that topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are [type casts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/cast) ***i.e.*** explicit type conversions.

---

In

```
x = *(unsigned long *)a; 
    ^                
//dereference
```

`(unsigned long *)a` casts `a` to a pointer to `unsigned long` and then dereferences it to assign its value to the local variable `x`.

---

```
(unsigned long)1
```

Simply casts `1` to `unsigned long` which by default would have the type `int`.

---

The first is needed because you can't dereference a `void` pointer, the second is there to avoid undefined behavior, see  [chux - Reinstate Monica's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66031321/what-does-unsigned-long1-and-unsigned-long-mean/66031428?noredirect=1#comment116750457_66031428). More details [here](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/INT13-C.+Use+bitwise+operators+only+on+unsigned+operands).

Comment: Re: "the second is not really (needed)" --> `(unsigned long)1 << i` without a cast is UB on the first iteration with 32-bit `int`.  A `(unsigned long long)` cast or `(uint64_t)` would be better.